# Dell XPS M1330 - power cable pulled by accident and now laptop won't turn on

Tags: power

I was using a laptop when the power cord was pulled out by accident.

Now when I plug in my laptop adapter into a power outlet the green light comes on as expected; but when I plug the outer side it into the laptop it goes out. I know it's not the adapter because I have 2 and they both experience the same issue.

I am quite certain the problem is a short in the laptop.

How or what do I check on the laptop to isolate the problem?

Comment: Since a laptop has a battery, pulling the power cable is usually not a problem.

Comment: Did the laptop ever hit the floor during this process?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the problem is a short circuit in the laptop, caused when the power cord was yanked out. In order to fix that you will need to open the laptop and look for damage near the power connector.

If your laptop still is in warranty then check if this is covered.

If you do not feel comfortable doing this then delegate it to someone else. Either to a shop or to someone you trust with this.

If you do this yourself, then first download the service manual for your laptop (not the owners manual). Take pictures of the laptop during disassembly and make sure you do not lose any screws. (Taping them in place often helps).

Depending on what you find you may be able to repair it yourself.

If you do not feel comfortable with that then take that as a strong signal not to even try -- ask someone else.